# Magento Change Order Status to Complete Without Capturing Payment

Tags: authorize.net, status

We had to roll back our Magento Install to a backup that was made 9 hours previous. In that time we had already processed some orders and captured payment. We use Authorize.net as our payment gateway. Now that we are rolled back to the backup the orders are there with a status of processing. Any ideas how I can push these orders through without re-capturing payment? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the solutions.

```
<?php 
    $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($order_id);
    $order->setData('state', "complete");
    $order->setStatus("complete");       
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

1
down vote
I think this is the solutions.

loadByIncrementId($order_id);
    $order->setData('state', "complete");
    $order->setStatus("complete");
    $history = $order->addStatusHistoryComment('Order was set to Complete by our automation tool.', false);
    $history->setIsCustomerNotified(false);
    $order->save();
?>
share improve this answer
BUT I WAS refund I did not like your stuff. I want to return it.